# c++ operator overload and usage

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, functor

bool operator()(Iterator it1, Iterator it2) const
 {
  return (*it1 < *it2);
 }

Can someone explain this function for me, thanks!
is this means overload the operator ()? after overload this, how to use it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means something like if you have a `class` called `Compare` for example:

```
Compare cmp;
....
if(cmp(it1, it2))
{
  std::cout << "First element is greater";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "Second element is greater";
}
```

Your object becomes like a `function` and it is called in `C++` world `Functor`.

Answer (score 4):

here is an example of overloading parentheses

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Overload/DemoOverload.htm

and another

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/99-overloading-the-parenthesis-operator/